# angular-ui global key bindings

Tags: angularjs, keyboard-shortcuts, angular-ui

I've started using the angular-ui keypress module and was wondering if there is a way to make global shortcut keys which work no matter where I'm placed within the body.

I've tried linking my ui-keydown to the body but as it's not in focus the key events are not fired.

eg:

```
<body ui-keydown="{'pageup':'nav_to($event, \'users\')'}">
```

I know I could just focus a div and attach the key bindings to that but what happens when I have a form and I want to access all the global key bindings within each field?

Comment: Did you try to bind the event to `$window` in your `controller` or `directive` link function?

Comment: I have now and it's complaining about 'object has no method 'apply'' so I tried putting an apply function in my nav_to method but it didn't recognise it. Is there a special way to do that?

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this in your main app controller:

```
    angular.element($window).on('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, except I had to change `$window` to `window`.

Comment: @BenFortune You should inject the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service as a dependency to the controller (or wherever it is used).

Comment: @user2301179 It was being used in a directive and was injected, though it didn't work.

Comment: I found out this approach sometimes would register more than once.

Comment: Pls correct me if I'm work, this method is triggered BEFORE the the default event (submitting a form if it's the go button ), so, there's a chance to capture the event in order to totally disable the "go" button from the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a controller and set it on the body tag, and set a key event callback as well:

```
<body ng-controller="keycontroller"  ui-keyup="{'enter':'callback($event)'}" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="test1" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="test2" />
</body>
```

And then set :

```
function keycontroller($scope) {
   $scope.test1= "It should work here...";
   $scope.test2= "...and also here.";

   $scope.callback = function fn($event) {
    console.log("Enter key pressed");
 };

}

var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.keypress']);
app.controller("keycontroller", keycontroller);
```