# How to create keyboard shortcuts to open html pages in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have to create keyboard shortcuts to open html pages in AngularJs. For example suppose there is Data.html page and keyboard shortcut as 'ctrl+d' then on pressing the 'ctrl+d' the Data.html page should open. Please provide any full example or useful link.

Thanks..

Comment: To find such things, use a search engine. We're not here to write your code: only to make your code correct.

Comment: Also ctrl+d binds to add bookmark, so you should be careful which combinations you use.

Comment: The right direction is probably mousetrap, https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: @Mike I said for example ctrl+d.. I am not going to use it and Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question:
[angular-ui global key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994457/angular-ui-global-key-bindings)

The AngularJS documentation should also provide a solution:

**Key capture**:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

Then use the standard StateChange

Or try something like this:
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/